# pygst - glimagesink callback

Tags: python, opengl, ctypes, gstreamer

I'm trying to use 'glimagesink' element with python.
The element (which is GObject inside) has `client-draw-callback` property which should (in C++ at least) contain a function (`bool func(uint t, uint w, uint h)`) pointer.
I've tried `element.set_property('client-draw-callback', myfunc)`, and creating function pointer with ctypes, but every time it says, `TypeError: could not convert argument to correct param type`

I could find any docs on using glimagesink or glfilterapp in python ):

The working c++ code:

```
gboolean drawCallback (GLuint texture, GLuint width, GLuint height)

{ ... } 

GstElement* glimagesink = gst_element_factory_make ("glimagesink", "glimagesink0");
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(glimagesink), "client-draw-callback", drawCallback, NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the problem you're having (as far as I can tell) but it's important to note that
this API has changed recently, now it expects a void pointer of data which allows you to pass in a handle to user_data (or NULL) when you connect your callback.

```
gboolean drawCallback (GLuint texture, GLuint width, GLuint height, gpointer data)
```

Comment: I just checked on #gstreamer, apparently that API can't be used from python.